# ode45 not passing arguments (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

I'm implementing a filtering algorithm in matlab and having some difficulty with parameter passing.

my dynamics are controlled by the function:

```
function zdot = VortexDynamics(t, z, vorticity)
for ii=1:length(vorticity),
    zdot(ii,1) = 1i/(2*pi) * sum(  vorticity([1:ii-1,ii+1:end])  .* ( z(ii) - z([1:ii-1,ii+1:end])  ) ./ (abs(z(ii) - z([1:ii-1,ii+1:end])  ).^2 ) ) ;  
end
end
```

I initially compute the trajectories with ode45, with no issue

```
 [t_true,z_true]=ode45(@VortexDynamics, tspan ,z0_true, OPTIONS, vorticity) ;
```

To implement the filter, I call a function for each time step:

```
 [z_a , Gam, z_ens] = EnKF_nonlinear(num_tracers, Func_Observation, Observations(:,ii),vorticity,  [prev_t t], z_ens, Gam, W,R, VortexDynamics, H, N) ;
```

EnKF_nonlinear is defined by:

```
 function [z_a, Gam_a, z_ens] = EnKF_nonlinear(num_tracers, Func_Observation, Observations,vorticity,  tspan, z0_est, Gam0_est, W,R, dynFunc, H,N )
```

Within EnKF_nonlinear, I need to integrate the dynamics again with ode45:

```
 for ii = 1:N

  [t_out, z_out] = ode45(dynFunc, tspan, z0_est(:,ii), vorticity);
  z_ens(:,ii) = z_out(end,:) ; 
 end
```

but I get the error:

```
 Error using VortexEnKF>VortexDynamics (line 85)
 Not enough input arguments.

 Error in VortexEnKF (line 63)
     [z_a , Gam, z_ens] = EnKF_nonlinear(num_tracers, Func_Observation,
     Observations(:,ii),vorticity,  [prev_t t], z_ens, Gam, W,R, VortexDynamics, H,
     N) ;
```

but VortexDynamics only requires t,z,vorticity as parameters.  I call ode45 the same way in both functions, but I only get the error when I call it through EnKFnonlinear.
I don't see how its not calling with the right number of parameters.  Any ideas?

Comment: Well one thing that I notice is that you call dynFunc without the @ handle in EnKF_Nonlinear. Also is dynFunc actually what you mean to use here? It looks like a variable from the way you use it in the definition of EnKF_nonlinear. If dynFunc is in fact a function, then don't include it as an input in the definition of EnKF_nonlinear. If it is not a function then ode45 can't use it as an input

Comment: I tried including @DynFunc in the definition of EnKF_Nonlinear, but it threw an "unexpected matlab operator" error.  I also tried using @DynFunc in the ode45 call, but got 
`Error: File: EnKF_nonlinear.m Line: 44 Column: 26
"dynFunc" was previously used as a variable, conflicting with its use here as the
name of a function or command.`

I think you're on to something.  Do you know how I should pass the function handle as an input variable?

Comment: I think you might be able to fix the error described above simply by replacing the line `function [z_a, Gam_a, z_ens] = EnKF_nonlinear(num_tracers, Func_Observation, Observations,vorticity,  tspan, z0_est, Gam0_est, W,R, dynFunc, H,N )` with `function [z_a, Gam_a, z_ens] = EnKF_nonlinear(num_tracers, Func_Observation, Observations,vorticity,  tspan, z0_est, Gam0_est, W,R, H,N )`. Then replacing `[t_out, z_out] = ode45(dynFunc, tspan, z0_est(:,ii),  vorticity);` with `[t_out, z_out] = ode45(@dynFunc, tspan, z0_est(:,ii), [], vorticity);`

Comment: The above assumes that the only input to dynFunc is vorticity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

silly me, 
I forgot to include a [] in the ode45 call as a placeholder for the precision options.

```
ode45(dynFunc, tspan, z0_est(:,ii), [], vorticity);
```

passes the vorticity parameter to dynFunc, and it works fine.

Comment: No, you shouldn't do that either. The proper way to pass parameters is via an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html#bsgprpq-8): `ode45(@(t,z)dynFunc(t,z,vorticity), tspan, z0_est(:,ii));`. See the [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html#bqxftul-1) right in the `ode45` documentation. The method you're using a vestige of old versions of Matlab and only exists for backwards compatibility. It's almost certainly less efficient.